# Method to find similar substrings from two strings

Tags: java, similarity

I'm using this piece of Java code to find similar strings:

`if( str1.indexof(str2) >= 0 || str2.indexof(str1) >= 0 ) .......`

but With `str1 = "pizzabase"` and `str2 = "namedpizzaowl"` it doesn't work.

### how do I find the common substrings i.e. "pizza"?

Comment: Do you want to find all of the common substrings, or only the [longest common substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150311/java-implementation-for-longest-common-substring-of-n-strings)?

Comment: To find  common substrings that are similar (but not identical), I would use a [sequence alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your algorithm says two strings are similar when they contain a common substring, then this algorithm will always return true; the empty string `""` is trivially a substring of every string. Also it makes more sense to determine the *degree* of similarity between strings, and return a number rather than a boolean.

This is a good algorithm for determining string (or more generally, sequence) similarity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over each letter in `str1`, checking for it's existence in `str2`. If it doesn't exist, move on to the next letter, if it does, increase the length of the substring in `str1` that you check for in `str2` to two characters, and repeat until no further matches are found or you have iterated through `str1`.

This will find all substrings shared, but is - like bubble sort - hardly optimal while a very basic example of how to solve a problem.

Something like this pseudo-ish example:

```
pos = 0
len = 1
matches = [];

while (pos < str1.length()) {

    while (str2.indexOf(str1.substring(pos, len))) {
       len++;
    }

    matches.push(str1.substring(pos, len - 1));
    pos++;
    len = 1;
}
```

Comment: @fateme: my provided code is not valid Java code, it is a pseudo code example that you need to understand and then implement.

Comment: @fateme: I had mistakenly left out resetting the `len` variable in my example. It's now in there.